# Create an index in the database composed of two columns, and one of them with specific values in PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have this table:

```js
Accounts {
  id,
  name,
  status_id,
  document,
  ...,
}
```

How to create a index unique composite by `status_id` and `document`
when `status_id` to values [1,3]

Example:

- User (1,name_1,1,1234) OK
- User (1,name_1,2,1234) OK
- User (1,name_1,1,1234) error constrain unique index
- User (1,name_1,3,1234) error constrain unique index
- User (1,name_1,4,1234) ok

I has test and not work:

- doesn't work because, can't add flag `UNIQUE`

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index 
ON "Accounts" (document, status_id) 
WHERE status_id = 1;
```

- don't work because, could add more register with values

```sql
CREATE INDEX index_name 
ON "Accounts" (document, status_id) 
WHERE status_id = 1 OR status_id = 3;
```

What's the query construction?

I'm using sequelize but the query would already serve ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What does `don't work because, could add more register with values` mean?

Comment: @MatBailie, is a flow useCase don´t have user with same document with status 1 or 3, but other status don`t have a problem repeat, the motivation for the problem, get a concurrence is pod an flow create account in database and create a two account with status Active do you understand ?

Comment: Like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/Y-pkHsMn (a unique key on the document, for status 1 or 3, but no unique enforcement for other status?)

Comment: @MatBailie, yes this work, I didn't think it would be possible to add just the field and a rule, thanks for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys answering the question thanks to the comment @MatBailie,
with the code:

`sql`

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name 
ON Accounts (document) 
WHERE status_id = 1 OR status_id = 3;
```

in `sequelize`:

```js
await queryInterface.addIndex('Accounts', ['document'], {
  name: 'idx_AC_document_status_id_active_or_created',
   unique: true,
   where: {
     status_id: { [Op.or]: [1, 3] },
   },
})
```